# Stretch text FPDF MultiCell

Tags: php, fpdf

There is a text (product description in the store) that I put in MultiCell, but it does not stretch to the whole page and leaves a lot of space on the right.By default, does not align.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNQJ1.jpg)

```
$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddFont('Verdana','','verdana.php');
$pdf->SetFont('Verdana','',12);
$pdf->SetTitle('PDF');
$pdf->SetTextColor(50,60,100);
$pdf->AddPage('P');
$pdf->MultiCell(190, 6, $product->description, 1, 'L');
```

Comment: Does the description include line breaks (CRLF)?

Comment: no line break...